# Let $f:B_1(0) \rightarrow B_1(0)$ be a holomorphic function with at least two fixed pionts. Show $f=id$.

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, fixed-points

> Tip: Transform the function $f$ so it has one fixed point at $0$.

We have the unit disk $B_1(0):=\{x\in X \mid d(0,x)<1 \}$ with the metric space $d$.

A fixed piont is a $x\in B_1(0)$  such that $f(x)=x$.

I have problems to understand the function. To my understanding, for all $x \in B_1(0)$ applies $f(x)=x$ because $d(0,x)=|x-0|=x$ for all $x$. Do I have to transform the function so I have **only** one fixed point at zero? Because to my understanding $0$ is already a fixed point of $f$.  I have no clue how to transform the function.

To show $f=id$, I could proof it with the identity theorem, which says:

> Let $G\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a domain and $f,g$ holomorphic functions on that domain. The following are equivalent:
>
> a) $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in G$.
>
> b) The set $\{z\in G \mid f(z)=g(z)\}$ has a limit point in G.
>
> c) There exist a $z\in G$ such that $f^{(n)}(z)=g^{(n)}(z)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N_0}$.

It is the first time I have to use the identity theorem and the task gives me a lot of problems. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I am sure they mean the following with the transformation: Given a fixed point $x \in B_1(0)$ with $f(x) = x$, define $\tilde{f}:B_1(x) \to B_1(x)$,  $\tilde{f}(z) = f(x-z)-x$, this then satisfies $\tilde{f}(0)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it has two fixed points, it must have a fixed point $z_0$ with $z_0\neq0$. It follows then from the Schwarz lemma that, for some $\omega\in\mathbb C$ such that $|\omega|=1$, $f(z)=\omega z$. And now it follows from the fact that $f(z_0)=z_0$ that $\omega=1$ and therefore that $f=\operatorname{id}$.

Comment: Amazing  how easy and short the proof is. Wondering why I had the tip with the transformation of the function with the fixed point at 0, especially when we need $z_0\neq 0$ for the proof.

Comment: @Mikemathics I have no idea.